# How to draw logarithmic line charts with nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there a way to draw logarithmic line charts with nvd3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a nvd3/d3 expert, but I've made something which seems to work like this for the `nv.models.lineChart`:

```
chart.yScale(d3.scale.log());
chart.yAxis.tickValues([1,10,100,1000,10000,1000000]);
chart.forceY([1,1000000]);
```

Notes:

1. The `yScale` function may be slightly different between models (`chart.lines.yScale` & `cart.lines2.yScale` on `nv.models.lineWithFocusChart` for example)
2. This doesn't seem to work with all models
3. <del>[D3 only supports base10 currently](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/928)</del>
   As of version [3.1.0](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases/v3.1.0) D3.js supports [arbitrary logarithm base](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-log_base), usage example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7621155